# NAudio: Record Wave, write it to file and visualize it at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wav, naudio

I am using NAudio to record from a WaveIn device and write it to a wave file. Afterwards the file is read and visualized (using WinForms).
Works fine.

Now a new requirement is to visualize it while recording, and still produce the .wav file.

I tried to use the bytes I get in the OnDataAvailable, but these produce a wrong output.

Is there an example available or can someone advice me how to convert the recorded bytes to the right format?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this question is too broad, i suggest you take a tour of the site and the help pages to better modify your question